# Как сериализовать Stream используя Newtonsoft json?

Tags: c#

У меня есть две структуры данных

```
public class Document
{
    private readonly ICollection<Image> _images = new List<Image>();

    public string Token { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateDownload { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string File { get; set; }

    public string HtmlMarkup { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public List<string> Titles { get; set; }

    public List<string> Text { get; set; }

    public List<string> TableContent { get; set; }

    public List<Image> Images => _images.ToList();

    public void AddImage(Image image)
    {
        _images.Add(image);
    }
}

public class Image
{
    public Stream FileStream { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Я ставлю документ в очередь используя RabbitMq, при сериализации Image.FileStream я получаю исключение, в котором говорится, что не удаётся сериализовать свойство с типом Stream

```
    public class RabbitMqReceiver : IReceiver
{
    private readonly IConnection _connection;
    private readonly IModel _channel;
    private readonly string _queue;

    public RabbitMqReceiver(string uri, string queue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queue))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queue));

        _queue = queue;

        IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.Uri = new Uri(uri);

        _connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();

        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

        _channel.QueueDeclare(
            queue: _queue,
            durable: true,
            exclusive: false,
            autoDelete: false);

        _channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
    }

    public event ReceivedEventHandler? Received;

    public void Start()
    {
        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, eventArgs) =>
        {
            byte[] message = eventArgs.Body.ToArray();

            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);

            var document = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(json);

            Received?.Invoke(document, eventArgs.DeliveryTag);
        };

        _channel.BasicConsume(
            queue: _queue,
            consumer: consumer);
    }

    
    public void Ack(ulong deliveryTag)
    {
        _channel?.BasicAck(
            deliveryTag: deliveryTag,
            multiple: false);
    }

    
    public void Requeue(Document document)
    {
        IBasicProperties properties = _channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        properties.Persistent = true;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);

        byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        _channel.BasicPublish(
            exchange: string.Empty,
            routingKey: _queue,
            basicProperties: properties,
            body: message);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _channel?.Dispose();
        _connection?.Dispose();
    }
}

    public class RabbitMqSender : ISender
{
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
    private readonly IConnection _connection;
    private readonly string _queue;
    private IModel _channel;



    public RabbitMqSender(string uri, string queue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queue))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queue));

        _queue = queue;

        IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.Uri = new Uri(uri);

        _connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
    }



    public void Send(Document document)
    {
        EnsureChannelIsPresent();

        IBasicProperties properties = _channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        properties.Persistent = true;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);

        byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        _channel.BasicPublish(
            exchange: string.Empty,
            routingKey: _queue,
            basicProperties: properties,
            body: message);
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
        _channel?.Dispose();
        _connection?.Dispose();
    }

    private void EnsureChannelIsPresent()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            if (_channel == null)
                CreateChannel();
        }
    }

    private void CreateChannel()
    {
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

        _channel.QueueDeclare(
            queue: _queue,
            durable: true,
            exclusive: false,
            autoDelete: false);

        _channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам сериализовать свойство типа `Stream`? Оно же только в рантайме имеет смысл. Добавьте атрибут `[JsonIgnore]` над свойством типа `Stream`, чтобы сериализатор его пропустил. И вообще непонятно, зачем вы файловый поток кладете в объект с картинкой. Открыл-загрузил-закрыл, больше поток не нужен.

Comment: Мне нужно передать Image дальше на сохранение, чтобы другой модуль брал Image.FileStream и сохранял картинку

Comment: У вас есть путь к файлу, его и передавайте. Открытый поток держать для этого не следует.

Comment: Если вам надо саму картинку живьем передать через AMQP, что выглядит совсем странно, типа много данных пойдет через канал, который по своей природе заточен на супербыструю передачу сообщений, то сохраните картинку как `byte[]` массив, чтобы данные были материализованы в памяти. Тогда этот массив можно будет сериализовать, но решение качать картинки через кролика выглядит очень сомнительным. На крайняк можно устанавливать соединение Named Pipe, чтобы устанавливать кросс-процессную передачу данных или писать данные на диск и передавать только путь к файлу. Вариантов много, но не через кролика.

Comment: Да уж, сериализовать поток - это как-то странно, мягко говоря )  Он может быть в каком угодно состоянии, это не законченный объект, который можно сохранить и полностью потом восстановить.